# distribute to install a package in python

Tags: python

I am trying to install a package named unicodecsv ->setup

python - setup.py

I got the following error message:

> ImportError: No module named setuptools

I found that Python 3 required to use distribute 0.6.39 to install the package. But what I do not know - how can I install my package once I have installed the distribute?

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Did you try installing setuptools from this website: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools and then retrying your `python setup.py` from before?

Comment: when I try to install the setup tools in gives error as follows:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 7, in <module>
    execfile(convert_path('setuptools/command/__init__.py'), d)
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
I explore on google some one says...setuptools has been replaced by distribute...but after installing distribute i don't know how to install a package....

Comment: even while installing distribute I got the error as follows:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
setuptools\dist.py", line 672, in handle_display_options
    sys.stdout.detach(), 'utf-8', errors, newline, line_buffering)
AttributeError: 'TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'detach'
Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.

Comment: can anybody help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Maybe you mix Python 3 and Python2